# Adding font color to text in Windows Phone 8 Application

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to change the font color of text in my Windows Phone 8 Application using the following code

```
RootFrame.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Purple);
```

This doesn't give me any change in the font color. I'm adding this line in **App.xaml.cs** constructor.

If I change the background color in the similar way it works. Please Can someone explain me what is the problem with this?

Comment: changing the foreground of rootframe wont change the foreground of all the text controls inside. You would have to set them individually.

Comment: But Background Color is getting changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me in setting the font color of the text throughout the Application instead of setting it individually for every control

```
(App.Current.Resources["PhoneForegroundBrush"] as SolidColorBrush).Color = Colors.Purple;
```

Answer (score 1):

Set name to your textbox using Name attribute in your XAML,

```
<TextBox Name="textBox1"....>
```

and change the Foreground color using,

```
textbox1.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
YourTextBoxName.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
```

Comment: This is working. What if I want to change for entire application and do not want to use templates for that?

Comment: There is no way that you can apply . you have to either go for style or do this way

Answer (score 0):

Create your Style within the Application Resources, Then You can Add Style using Code.

**Create Application Resource :**

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="MyTextBox">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="90" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Azure"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Purple"></Setter>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

Then You can style like this.

```
YourTextBoxName.Style = Application.Current.Resources["MyTextBox"] as Style;
```